Four out puzzle: Get rid of a six digit number in 4 moves
I saw this puzzle in an old book with math games. The objective of the puzzle is to get rid of a six digit number in four moves so that the calculator will read 0.
You start with a six-digit number with all digits being different. You can use two-digit numbers and any of the +-*/ operations.
For example, in the book, you start with 542681. In the first move you subtract 81 to get 542600, then divide by 50 to get 10852, then divide by 52 to get 208.6923 and the final move by dividing with 99, resulting in 2.10800. And it says that move 3 was wrong and therefore we lost this round.
There is a claim in the book that once you get a sense of the puzzle, you will be surprised at how fast a number can be eliminated, however, I can't come up with a strategy to solve it.
I was thinking at each step to divide by the largest two-digit number but a lot of times it will not be possible.
Does anyone know about this puzzle? Have I misunderstood the rules? What is the best strategy?

Are you looking for a general solution to this puzzle?

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question? (Specifically, what was the book's name?)

If you say 0 is a 2-digit number (00) then every number can get to 0 with 1 step using *0 (which gives 0) or /0 (which gives ERROR and 0). But 00 displays as 0.

A general strategy that generally works within 5 moves is as follows: substract some 2-digit number to get to a multiple of 99, divide by 99, substract some 2-digit number to get to a multiple of 99, divide by 99, result is 2 digits so one can substract itself to get 0.

This is not always possible (under the assumption that every intermediate result must be an integer, which can likely be removed). In order to reach exactly zero, the last operation must have been a subtraction (or addition). Hence, the game is equivalent to reaching a 2-digit integer (positive or negative) in three moves or less. But this is not possible: The largest number you can bring down to two digits in two moves is clearly $99^3=970299$. Thus, if we start out with any number larger than $99^3+99$ that is coprime to all numbers from $2$ to $99$, we can start the game only with a subtraction (or increase the number even further). Such numbers exist in abundance, for instance the prime $999983$ will do.

Fwiw, I tried brute force.  The first number that requires 5 operations is 533362.  There are plenty of values after that that cannot be done in 4 operations.

@FlorianF It's interesting to me that the number is still that large, in a sense. I would have expected my crude argument to be much farther from the truth

I think the first number that requires 5 operations and has no repeated digits, as stated in the question is 560389. It has no two-digit divisors (it is 149 times 3761) and it is not within 99 of any number that is the product of three two-digit numbers: the closest such numbers on either side are 560280 and 560522.

Oops, I didn't see the "all different" condition.  And I included 1-digit numbers in the operation.  Not sure it is allowed.
